# Change user password command not working for salt stack

Tags: salt-stack

```
sudo salt 'vultr.guest' shadow.set_password user '$6$SALTsalt$3ILXYcVfBr/SosT4SMXKrqtgfR6BYm2XgTLQ/Xy95gpNYT7MOEToBUWw1gtV15U2IVFngh0DtUSsgR6Khlldm1'
```

When running this command to change the user password using salt I return this error:

```
The minion function caused an exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/minion.py", line 1934, in _thread_return
        function_name, function_args, executors, opts, data
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/minion.py", line 1892, in _execute_job_function
        return_data = self.executors[fname](opts, data, func, args, kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 149, in __call__
        return self.loader.run(run_func, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1201, in run
        return self._last_context.run(self._run_as, _func_or_method, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/contextvars/__init__.py", line 38, in run
        return callable(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1216, in _run_as
        return _func_or_method(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/executors/direct_call.py", line 10, in execute
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 149, in __call__
        return self.loader.run(run_func, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1201, in run
        return self._last_context.run(self._run_as, _func_or_method, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/contextvars/__init__.py", line 38, in run
        return callable(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/loader/lazy.py", line 1216, in _run_as
        return _func_or_method(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/salt/modules/linux_shadow.py", line 400, in set_password
        comps[2] = lstchg
    IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I've used salt's password hashing python script to generate the password. I've tried deleting the user then adding it back with the user.remove and the user.add modules.

Answer (score 0):

check your shadow file. it sounds like you have turned password aging off. which seems a rather insecure way to operate.

the line in question is checking the last change field of the user you are trying to change the password of.

the format is `username:password:last change:min:max:warn:disable:ddate`

the only time last change should be blank is if password ageing has been turned off. it should be the date of the last change in days since Jan 1st 1970.